# how can i set foreign key set automatically to the user in my person field

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

this is my views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def user_edit(request, user_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            i = form.save(commit=False)
            i.user = request.user
            i.save()
            return redirect('list')
        else:
            form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, "home/intro.html", {'form': form})

    else:
        return render(request, "home/intro.html")
```

this is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Profile


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

this is my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='imgs/')
    about = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=False)
    phnum = models.IntegerField()
    uname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.about
```

how can i set person to that user id that is currently logged in...???
i wanted to save user id to that foreign key so that if i delete user then profile of that user will also be deleted

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('signup/', views.user_crete, name="signup"),
    path('login/', views.user_login, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.user_logout, name="logout"),
    path('edit/', views.user_edit, name="edit"),
    path('list/', views.user_list, name="list"),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h2 class="text-center mt-2">Setup Your Profile</h2>
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">

<form class="mt-2" method="post" action="{% url 'edit' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Uname</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ user.username }}" name="uname" value="{{ user.username }}" readonly>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Profile Picture</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="img">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>About Your Self</label><br>
    <input type="textbox" class="form-control" placeholder="Write about yourself" name="about">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Phone Number</label><br>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Number" name="phnum">
  </div>



  <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button></center>
</form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

i added my template from where i crate profile of particular users and i also added urls.py file for more continent

Answer (score 1):

In you model, `person` is the field for User but your view you wrote `i.user` you should write `i.person`:

```py
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def user_edit(request, user_id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

        form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=user)

        if form.is_valid():
            i = form.save(commit=False)
            i.person = request.user  # change here
            i.save()
            return redirect('list')
        else:
            form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, "home/intro.html", {'form': form})

    else:
        return render(request, "home/intro.html")
```

**urls.py**
In your url pass the user id

```py
path('edit/<int:user_id>/', views.user_edit, name="edit"),
```

**template**
Pass `user.id` to form action

```html
<form class="mt-2" method="post" action="{% url 'edit' user.id %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   ...
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222905/discussion-on-answer-by-carlos-how-can-i-set-foreign-key-set-automatically-to-th).